# C++ boost or STL `y += f(x)` type algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost

I know I can do this `y[i] += f(x[i])` using transform with two input iterators.
however it seems somewhat counterintuitive and more complicated than for loop.

Is there a more natural way to do so using existing algorithm in boost or Stl.  I could not find clean equivalent.

here is transform (y = y + a*x):

```
using boost::lambda;
transform(y.begin(), y.end(), x.begin(), y.begin(), (_1 + scale*_2);
//  I thought something may exist:
transform2(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), (_2 + scale*_1);
// it does not, so no biggie. I will write wrapper
```

Thanks

Comment: @Arak  I have few daxpy-like loops I would like to C++-ize

Comment: It would help if you'd show in your question an example of a call to transform() that you find "counterintuitive and more complicated than for loop"

Comment: The code you presented so far would compile just fine as-is (assuming x, y, i, and f are properly defined. That pretty much leaves everyone mystified as to what you need transform for.

Comment: For something this simple, stick with the for loop.  It works, and it's easy to read and understand.  Trying to do a simple task like this with a transform and a functor would needlessly complicate it, and make it harder for the maintenance programmer to read.

Comment: @Tim I hear you.I was somewhat ambivalent, but I think it simplifies reading, at least for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

As you noted you can use `transform` with a number of predicates, some more or less automatically generated:

```
std::vector<X> x = /**/;
std::vector<Y> y = /**/;

assert(x.size() == y.size());

//
// STL-way
//
struct Predicate: std::binary_function<X,Y,Y>
{
  Y operator()(X lhs, Y rhs) const { return rhs + f(lhs); }
};

std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), y.begin(), Predicate());

//
// C++0x way
//
std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), y.begin(),
               [](X lhs, Y rhs) { return rhs += f(lhs); });
```

Now, if we had a `vector` with the range of indices, we could do it in a more "pythony" way:

```
std::vector<size_t> indices = /**/;


//
// STL-way
//
class Predicate: public std::unary_function<size_t, void>
{
public:
  Predicate(const std::vector<X>& x, std::vector<Y>& y): mX(x), mY(y) {}
  void operator()(size_t i) const { y.at(i) += f(x.at(i)); }
private:
  const std::vector<X>& mX;
  std::vector<Y>& mY;
};

std::foreach(indices.begin(), indices.end(), Predicate(x,y));

//
// C++0x way
//
std::foreach(indices.begin(), indices.end(), [&](size_t i) { y.at(i) += f(x.at(i)); });

//
// Boost way
//
BOOST_FOREACH(size_t i, indices) y.at(i) += f(x.at(i));
```

I don't know if there could be something to do with views, they normally allow some pretty syntax. Of course it's a bit difficult here I think because of the self-modifying `y`.

Comment: +1 for suggesting newer syntaxes, but still staying correct in the current standard.

Comment: `Predicate` is a function that returns `bool`. Use `UnaryFunction` or `BinaryFunction` names here.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: I guess I am more lax, I usually use Predicate for any reified action, I usually think of it like in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lojban :)

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer**: I have no practical experience with valarray, so please don't take this answer as an "advice", but more as a "request for comments". In particular, I have no idea of how efficient this would be. But I'm curious as the notation seems pretty intuitive to me:

With x and y being `valarray<int>` and with a function `int f(int)`, would:

```
y += x.apply(&f);
```

do what you want?

Comment: seems the `y` and `x` are mixed up, `y[i] = f(x[i])`

Comment: thanks.unfortunately I have to work with memory already allocated

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with a simple loop?

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  y[i] += f(x[i]);
```

In general even in Fortran it would be:

```
forall(i=0:n) y(i) += f(x(i))
```

Though with restrictions on `f`, `x`, `y` it could be written as:

```
y += f(x)
```

`transform()` variant is more generic and verbose:

```
std::transform(boost::begin(y), boost::end(y), boost::begin(x), 
               boost::begin(y), _1 += bind(f, _2));
```

It might be possible to write `zip()` using `boost::zip_iterator`:

```
foreach (auto v, zip(y, z)) 
  v.get<0>() += f(v.get<1>());
```

where `foreach` is `BOOST_FOREACH`.

Here's variant similar to [@Matthieu M.'s indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745146/c-boost-or-stl-y-fx-type-algorithm/2745788#2745788):

```
foreach (size_t i, range(n)) // useless compared to simple loop
  y[i] += f(x[i]);
```

#### Possible `range()` Implementation

```
template<class T, class T2>
std::pair<boost::counting_iterator<T>, 
          boost::counting_iterator<T> > 
range(T first, T2 last) {
  return std::make_pair(boost::counting_iterator<T>(first), 
                        boost::counting_iterator<T>(last));
}

template<class T>
std::pair<boost::counting_iterator<T>, 
          boost::counting_iterator<T> > 
range(T last) {
  return range<T>(0, last);
}
```

#### Draft (broken) `zip()` Implementation

```
template<class Range1, class Range2>
struct zip_return_type {
  typedef boost::tuple<
    typename boost::range_iterator<Range1>::type,
    typename boost::range_iterator<Range2>::type> tuple_t;

  typedef std::pair<
    boost::zip_iterator<tuple_t>,
    boost::zip_iterator<tuple_t> > type;
};

template<class Range1, class Range2>
typename zip_return_type<Range1, Range2>::type
zip(Range1 r1, Range2 r2) {
  return std::make_pair(
    boost::make_zip_iterator(
      boost::make_tuple(boost::begin(r1), boost::begin(r2))),
    boost::make_zip_iterator(
      boost::make_tuple(boost::end(r1), boost::end(r2))));
}
```

Comment: hello.
overall, I agree with you. there is a number of indices already in function, and trying to reduce visual complexity little bit.  to me, transform looks more self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways. I suppose `y` is some kind of your own container following the `iterator` idea.

The first way is to write another routine that takes `y`, `x` and some functor as a param. Generally it would do the same `y[i] += f(x[i])` stuff, but if you name it correctly, this would make your code cleaner and easier to understand.

Another way is operator `+=` (or `+`, or better together) overloading so that (let's say `y` has a `container` type) it would look the following way:

```
container& operator+ (functor_type& functor)
```

Here your functor should be a struct / class declared the following way:

```
class functor {
private:
   container c;
public:
   functor (container& c) : c(c) { }
   container operator() (void) { (...) - your actions on container here }
};
```

This way you could write `y += f(x)` and it would be ok. However, I wouldn't recommend this way of managing your code, because all these operator overloads on your own datatypes generally make the code harder to understand.

Comment: Sorry, but -1. It may be confusing for you, but it is the correct way to use the STL. You should prefer algorithm calls to explicit loops.

Comment: @Billy I suspect you have given -1 to the answer when you wanted to give it to the answer

Comment: @Vicente: What? (Is that a typo?)